# gstreamer records

Tags: video, ffmpeg, audio-recording, gstreamer

I use the following command to record audio and video from my webcam

```
gst-launch-0.10 v4l2src ! video/x-raw-yuv,width=640,height=480,framerate=30/1 ! \
             tee name=t_vid ! queue ! videoflip method=horizontal-flip ! \
             xvimagesink sync=false t_vid. ! queue ! \
             videorate ! video/x-raw-yuv,framerate=30/1 ! queue ! mux. \
             autoaudiosrc ! audiorate ! audio/x-raw-int,rate=48000,channels=1,depth=16 ! queue ! \
             audioconvert ! queue ! mux. avimux name=mux ! \
             filesink location=video.avi
```

And the result is correct in term of synchronicity between the flows. However the avi file is very big since that's uncompressed data...
Could you advice me howto reduce the size of the records. Note that I after recording I split audio and video in separate files for processing. It is crucial to keep the synchronicity.

*** Edit ***

I tried to use ffmpeg to compress the avi files using this command:

```
ffmpeg -i video.avi -vcodec msmpeg4v2 output.avi
```

But it seems that bitrate is invalid (N/A since its raw data ?)
Here is the output:

```
Input #0, avi, from 'video.avi':
Duration: 00:00:00.00, start: 0.000000, bitrate: -2147483 kb/s
  Stream #0.0: Video: rawvideo, yuv420p, 640x480, 30 tbr, 30 tbn, 30 tbc
  Stream #0.1: Audio: pcm_s16le, 48000 Hz, 1 channels, s16, 768 kb/s
[buffer @ 0xef57e0] w:640 h:480 pixfmt:yuv420p
Incompatible sample format 's16' for codec 'ac3', auto-selecting format 'flt'
[ac3 @ 0xedece0] channel_layout not specified
[ac3 @ 0xedece0] No channel layout specified. The encoder will guess the layout, but it     might be incorrect.
[ac3 @ 0xedece0] invalid bit rate
Output #0, avi, to 'output.avi':
  Stream #0.0: Video: msmpeg4v2, yuv420p, 640x480, q=2-31, 200 kb/s, 90k tbn, 30 tbc
  Stream #0.1: Audio: ac3, 48000 Hz, mono, flt, 200 kb/s
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0.0 -> #0.0
  Stream #0.1 -> #0.1
Error while opening encoder for output stream #0.1 - maybe incorrect parameters such as bit_rate, rate, width or height
```

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you could do: (Say 900k video and 64k audio. Since you want 48kHz sampling you need to give atleast 64Kbits bitrate)

```
gst-launch-0.10 v4l2src ! video/x-raw-yuv,width=640,height=480,framerate=30/1 ! \
         tee name=t_vid ! queue ! videoflip method=horizontal-flip ! \
         xvimagesink sync=false t_vid. ! queue ! \
         videorate ! video/x-raw-yuv,framerate=30/1 ! queue ! ffmpegcolorspace ! ffenc_mpeg4 bitrate=900000 ! mux. \
         autoaudiosrc ! audiorate ! audio/x-raw-int,rate=48000,channels=1,depth=16 ! queue ! \
         audioconvert ! lamemp3enc bitrate=64 target=1 ! queue !  mux. avimux name=mux ! \
         filesink location=video.avi
```

If you prefer to get smaller size and don't mind a mp4 I would suggest replace ffenc_mp4 with x264enc and avimux with mp4mux.
If you are using x264enc with any other muxer [not mp4mux] remember to also set property byte-stream=1 for x264enc.

To get the properties of any element type gst-inspect 
So lamemp3enc info can be obtained by doing
gst-inspect lamemp3enc.

Answer (score 0):

you could strick lamemp3enc into the audio branch and ffenc_mpeg4 (or ffenc_msmpeg4) into the video branch.

Comment: could you give the syntax plz

Comment: av501 gave you an example. You can also find such example in gstreamer man pages and plugin docs.